# How to run an application using python compiled code in Python3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.7, compiled

I have developed an application using Python2 and later ported into Python3. In python2, I can use the compiled python files to run the application on any computer without having the source code. However, I'm unable to  run the application on other computers without having the source code with Python3.7 version. I'm trying to hide my source code from being copied. I understand that there are decompile softwares that can decompile a compiled file but this is the minimum that I wanted to do. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or something else needs to be done. I greatly appreciate your help here.

Below is a structure of my code:

```
a.py main file that imports b.py file
b.py file imports c.py file
c.py file imports d.py file
```

I'm OKAY code in a.py being visible to the user as it contains the call to b.py only.
Thanks!!

Comment: Can you please share what os you want to run the file on?

Comment: PrateekSaini...I'm running on windows 10

Comment: What we can do is we can make it to an exe format

Comment: Can you explain me more about creating an exe file or point me towards that link?

Comment: yeah sure i can give me a mail id I'll contact you over there